# Wordpress, displaying custom fields content of specific category of post, in a slider, using a custom loop

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm beginner with PHP and maybe someone can help me with this...

I have this slider, which works when I use different images in it:

```
<a id="prev1">prev</a><a id="next1">next</a>
<div id="slider">
  <img src="/images-custom/telephone-icon.jpg"/>
  <img src="/images-custom/mail-icon.jpg"/>
  <img src="/images-custom/linkedin-icon.jpg"/>
</div>
```

but instead of using images, I want to use my custom loop to display the custom field and the permalink in the slider.

Here's my loop:

```
<?php 
$catquery1 = new WP_Query( 'cat=9&posts_per_page=1&orderby=date&order=ASC' ); 
while($catquery1->have_posts()) : $catquery1->the_post(); ?>

<?php the_field('slogan_dactualites_sur_la_page_accueil'); ?>

<?php if($GLOBALS['q_config']['language']=="en"){ ?>
    <a href="<? the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
<?php }else{ ?>
    <a href="<? the_permalink(); ?>">Lire la suite</a>
<?php } ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

If somebody can help me it would be really appreciated!!!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't said what slider you're using and it's impossible to discern what the limitations of this slider are, my code is completely without testing or warranty.

```
<a id="prev1">prev</a><a id="next1">next</a>
<div id="slider">

$catquery1 = new WP_Query( 'cat=9&posts_per_page=1&orderby=date&order=ASC' ); 
while($catquery1->have_posts()) : $catquery1->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="slider-element">
    <?php the_field('slogan_dactualites_sur_la_page_accueil'); ?>

    <?php if($GLOBALS['q_config']['language']=="en"){ ?>
        <a href="<? the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
    <?php }else{ ?>
        <a href="<? the_permalink(); ?>">Lire la suite</a>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using JQuery slider, Cycle :

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
                       $('#slider').cycle({ 
                       fx:     'scrollHorz', 
                       prev:   '#prev1', 
                       next:   '#next1', 
                       timeout: 0, 
                       rev: true
                       });
                       </script>

Comment: @user3271655 Then if that's the case, this code will work completely fine.

Comment: I got it... a p tag or any kind of tag was missing. Need it to display text in the slider.

Comment: @user3271655 What are you saying? `<div class="slider-element">` has been there the entire time.

Comment: Div do not work in this case... I dont know why. I know your Div was ther, but I cant explain... only p was working